# Svg doesn't show

Tags: image, svg

I used [this](http://html5up.net/big-picture) temaplte for my web. I edited it and it was be ok at my localhost. I uploaded it to hosting and arrows in .svg doesn't show. Here is source code:

HTML:

```
<a href="#one" class="button style2 down">More</a>
```

CSS:

```
.dark .button.style2.down {
                background-image: url('images/dark-arrow.svg');
            }
```

SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="36px" height="36px" viewBox="0 0 36 36" zoomAndPan="disable" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<style type="text/css"><![CDATA[ line { stroke: #fff; stroke-width: 1; } ]]></style>
<line x1="0" y1="18" x2="18" y2="36" />
<line x1="36" y1="18" x2="18" y2="36" />
<line x1="18" y1="36" x2="18" y2="0" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that your webhost is returning the right MIME type for SVG.  It should be "image/svg+xml".

You can check by looking at the request using the Network tab in Firebug or your browser developer tools.

Comment: Type is text/plain, here is a problem, thanks. But how can I change it?

Comment: It depends on your webserver.  Some instructions for Apache, for example, are here: http://kaioa.com/node/45